# How can I find the top 5 values from a range, only from a specific month?

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
=IF(MONTH(D2:D100)=7,LARGE($F$2:$F$100,K19),0)
```

I am trying to find the top 5 values from the range F2:F100, but i am only interested in the values from a sale during the month of July. The range D2:D100 consists of dates ranging from July to December. I tried to use the above function but it returned a value of "0."

To set the formula I  created a helper column with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 in cells K19:K23.

Comment: With the use of K19:K23, you just need to change the formula to `=LARGE(INDEX((MONTH(D2:D100)=7)*$F$2:$F$100,),K19)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this formula. It has to be entered as an array formula. Select 5 horizontal cells. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>=</kbd> enter the formula and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=LARGE(--(MONTH(N2:N26)=4)*O2:O26,{1,2,3,4,5})
```

For 5 vertical cells, use

```
=LARGE(--(MONTH(N2:N26)=4)*O2:O26,{1;2;3;4;5})
```

`N2:N26` is my date range
`O2:O26` is my data range and I am checking for the month of April hence `"=4"`

[image: Array Formula]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why the `--`?

Comment: `MONTH(N2:N26)=4` gives you an array of TRUEs and FALSEs. the `--` converts the TRUEs to 1s and FALSEs to Zeros. Then we can use this numeric array to multiply with other arrays.

Comment: HAHA. I never tried this without the `--`. I just did and it worked fine.

Comment: The `--` changes from bool to numeric (that is true). But you are using `*` with it, which also changes it to numeric here. This way the `--` can be skipped here... I just wanted to know if there may be a different reason you did not skip it. Anyways: a good solid solution. (You may offer the column-array (`{1;2;3;4;5}`) so it can be used in one column (as the OP already prepared `K19:K23` and want it that way) ;)

Comment: Great solution! i most probably would not get to this by myself.. thanks!